# Showing non-db field in OSGMGeoAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin, geodjango

I have a django model that is a `GeoModel`. I have one field on the model that is a `LineString`, but its non implemented as a typical `LineStringField`. I have defined a `@property` method that returns a LineString object.

I want this LineString object to be displayed on a map in this model's admin.

The problem is that OSMGeoAdmin is designed to automatically pick up geographical fields and make them into maps. The code isn't intelligent enough to know that I want that property to be displayed in a map.

If I add my property to the `readonly_fields` list it will show up there, but it will be textual, not as a map.

How can I make custom properties into a map using OSMGeoAdmin?

edit: just to be clear, I am not interested in editing this value. The data is not stored in the database, so it wouldn't make any sense to do it. I just want to see the data in a map, in a read-only sense.